# extreme newbie here, can anyone check whats wrong with my code? why isn't the style applying?

Tags: html

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nerko+One&display=swap"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster"
  rel="stylesheet"
  type="text/css"
/>
<style>
 
    background-image: url("https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/17520.jpg");
 

  #not-working {
    font-family: Lobster, monospace;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
  }
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
<p id="not-working">hello world</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why the id `#not-working` is  not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `background-image: url("https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/17520.jpg")`, because that's a wrong line. You have to do that in some other way, like `body{background-image:[...];}`
Otherwise it works.

```html
<style>
#not-working {
  font-family: Lobster, monospace;
  font-size: 45px;
  text-align: center;             
  color: white;
}
body{
  background-image: url("https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/17520.jpg");
}
</style>
<p id="not-working"> hello world</p>
```

Comment: Don't forget about the `<head>` and `<body>` tags as well!

Comment: Actually head and body don't matter because it's such a simple case and the browser with the HTML5 stuff have to be able to figure out what is what.

Comment: I completely agree. But this being a beginner's question, would it not be best to show good practice through a complete and corrected answer? If not through a demonstrated example, then at least through a list of attention points.

Comment: Okay, I guess it doesn't hurt to do that.

Comment: For some reason it says that there's code that isn't formatted properly so I can't change it.

Comment: @Lae I tried removing the shifting and do all kinds of stuff but it doesn't allow me to do that so I just gave up at some point.

Answer (score 1):

`background-image` is not applied on anything. Apply it on body:

```
<style>
body {
  background-image: url("https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/17520.jpg");
}

#not-working {
  font-family: Lobster, monospace;
  font-size: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

You have also messed up your code. Use a proper HTML Format:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nerko+One&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <style>
      body {
        background-image: url("https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/17520.jpg");
      }

      #not-working {
        font-family: Lobster, monospace;
        font-size: 45px;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="not-working">hello world</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because is your `background-image: url("https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/17520.jpg")` outside of the element. may you can try it!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nerko+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>

#not-working {
font-family: Lobster, monospace;
font-size: 45px;
text-align: center;             
color: white;
background-image: url("https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/17520.jpg")
}
</style>
<p id="not-working"> hello world</p>
```